# How to skip through same tags in BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing code for Scrapers and more and more become a fan of Python and especially BeautifulSoup.

Still... When parsing through html I came across a difficult part that I could only use in a not so beautiful way.

I want to scrape HTML Code and especially the following snippet:

```
<div class="title-box">
    <h2>
        <span class="result-desc">
            Search results <strong>1</strong>-<strong>10</strong> out of <strong>10,009</strong> about <strong>paul mccartney</strong><a href="alert/settings" class="title-email-alert-promo x-title-alerts-promo">Create email Alert</a>
        </span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

So what I do is I identify the div by using:

```
comment = TopsySoup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'title-box'})
```

Then the ugly part comes in. To catch the number I want to have: 10,009 I use:

```
catcher = comment.strong.next.next.next.next.next.next.next
```

Can somebody tell me if there is a nicer way?

Answer (score 3):

How about `comment.find_all('strong')[2].text`?

It can actually be shortened as `comment('strong')[2].text`, since calling a `Tag` object as though it is a function is the same as calling `find_all` on it.

```
>>> comment('strong')[2].text
u'10,009'
```